# Populate database with sample (fake) data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, populate

What is the best way to populate the development database with sample data?

FactoryGirl seems to be useful for tests, but not suitable for development.
Populator is not updated to Rails 3.

Should I use something like Faker or Forgery in a rake task?

Answer (score 6):

I'm using ffaker and populator gems in a rake task to create fake data in a Rails 3 project.  Here's an example:

```
desc 'Create some fake tickets'
  task :tickets => :environment do
  Ticket.populate NUM_TICKETS do |t|
    t.title = Faker::Lorem.sentence(word_count=15)
    t.details = Faker::HipsterIpsum.paragraphs(sentence_count=3)
    t.group_id = rand(6)+1 # random group_id [1..6]
    t.status_id = 1
    t.priority_id = rand(3)+1 # random priority_id [1..3]
    t.contact_id = rand(NUM_CONTACTS)+1 # random contact_id [1..NUM_CONTACTS]
    t.creator_id = rand(6)+2 # random created_by [2..7]
    t.created_at = CREATION_PERIOD.sample
  end
end
```

Full rake task here:
https://github.com/leesmith/ticket_mule/blob/edge/lib/tasks/faker.rake

Answer (score 2):

This looks promising :
https://github.com/paulelliott/fabrication

Answer (score -1):

Use faker gem in your Gemfile, bundle.. and... put this in your seeds.rb

```
100.times do
  Post.create({
    title: Faker::Lorem.sentence(3),
    body: Faker::Lorem.paragraph,
    author_name: Faker::Name.name
    })
end
```

$rake db:seed

Comment: You shouldn't put sample data in seeds.rb: this file is meant to load real data into the database (i.e. geodata, cities, list of operating systems... and defaults in general).